# Samba won't join computers to domain anymore

Tags: samba, active-directory, domain-server, samba4

**DISCLAMER:**
I'm still trying to fully learn and understand how to properly maintain a samba domain controller.

**The Problem:**

I had a working samba installation with AD controlle but now, just a month after my last computer join, it won't work anymore. On Windows it says "unknown user or password" but I've checked them to be correct.

I tried setting the log level to 3 in "smb.conf" and while trying to join a computer this gets logged:

```
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.018256,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ admuser@example.net from ipv4:172.27.2.58:50124 for krbtgt/example.net@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.039839,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: 128
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.040080,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.040191,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.040341,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: No preauth found, returning PREAUTH-REQUIRED -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.043598,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.054880,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ admuser@example.net from ipv4:172.27.2.58:50125 for krbtgt/example.net@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.076255,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client sent patypes: encrypted-timestamp, 128
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.076483,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for PKINIT pa-data -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.076587,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Looking for ENC-TS pa-data -- admuser@example.net
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.077527,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: ENC-TS Pre-authentication succeeded -- admuser@example.net using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.077840,  3] ../../auth/auth_log.c:635(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [Kerberos KDC,ENC-TS Pre-authentication] user [(null)]\[admuser@example.net] at [Tue, 04 Oct 2022 12:11:58.077747 CEST] with [aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96] status [NT_STATUS_OK] workstation [(null)] remote host [ipv4:172.27.2.58:50125] became [EXAMPLE]\[admuser] [S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1104]. local host [NULL] 
  {"timestamp": "2022-10-04T12:11:58.086113+0200", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 2}, "eventId": 4624, "logonId": "c61be2b0d84a3e12", "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_OK", "localAddress": null, "remoteAddress": "ipv4:172.27.2.58:50125", "serviceDescription": "Kerberos KDC", "authDescription": "ENC-TS Pre-authentication", "clientDomain": null, "clientAccount": "admuser@example.net", "workstation": null, "becameAccount": "admuser", "becameDomain": "EXAMPLE", "becameSid": "S-1-5-21-578677625-3635414378-1858279571-1104", "mappedAccount": "admuser", "mappedDomain": "EXAMPLE", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96", "duration": 31663}}
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.160727,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: AS-REQ authtime: 2022-10-04T12:11:58 starttime: unset endtime: 2022-10-04T22:11:58 renew till: 2022-10-11T12:11:58
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.161033,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, arcfour-hmac-md5, 24, -135, 3, using aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96/aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.161206,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Requested flags: renewable-ok, canonicalize, renewable, forwardable
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.165799,  3] ../../source4/smbd/service_stream.c:67(stream_terminate_connection)
  stream_terminate_connection: Terminating connection - 'kdc_tcp_call_loop: tstream_read_pdu_blob_recv() - NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED'
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.178036,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed to verify authenticator checksum: Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type rsa-md5, key type aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
[2022/10/04 12:11:58.178282,  3] ../../source4/auth/kerberos/krb5_init_context.c:80(smb_krb5_debug_wrapper)
  Kerberos: Failed parsing TGS-REQ from ipv4:172.27.2.58:50126
```

As you can see, the authentication here is reported to be successful. So far it's the same issue as [here](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1065/windows-client-unable-join-domain-samba-4-domain-controller-logon-failure-unknown-user-name), so I tried the following commands:

```
 root@SMBDC1:~# host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.example.net
    _ldap._tcp.example.net has SRV record 0 100 389 smbdc1.example.net.
 root@SMBDC1:~# host -t SRV _kerebros._udp.example.net
    Host _kerebros._udp.example.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
 root@SMBDC1:~# host -t A focal.exapmle.net
    Host focal.example.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
    
 root@SMBDC1:~# dig -t SRV _kerebros._udp.frankini.net
    
    ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> -t SRV _kerebros._udp.frankini.net
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 138
    ;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
    
    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;_kerebros._udp.frankini.net.   IN      SRV
    
    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    frankini.net.           3600    IN      SOA        
    smbdc1.frankini.net. hostmaster.        frankini.net. 55 900 600 86400 3600
    
    ;; Query time: 3 msec
    ;; SERVER: 172.27.1.1#53(172.27.1.1)
    ;; WHEN: Fri Oct 07 21:44:12 CEST 2022
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 99
```

This originally worked but now i get "**Host not found**"... what could have changed?

*My setup*

```
router:     172.27.0.1
smbdc:      172.27.1.1
dns:        172.27.1.2

dhcp range: 172.27.2.2 - 172.27.2.254

Samba runs on an Orange Pi Zero and I connect to it through Putty and FileZilla

I route communication between the xxx.xxx.0.xxx, xxx.xxx.1.xxx and xxx.xxx.2.xxx ip ranges and set the network mask to be 255.255.0.0
```

*System*

```
 OS:    Armbian 22.05.3 Focal with Linux 5.15.48-sunxi
 SAMBA: Samba version 4.13.17-Ubuntu
```

*smb.conf*

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    dns forwarder = 172.27.1.2
    netbios name = SMBDC1
    realm = EXAMPLE.NET
    server role = active directory domain controller
    workgroup = EXAMPLE
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
    host msdfs = yes
    log level = 3

[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No

[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/example.net/scripts
    read only = No
```

**The Question:**

I think I'm understanding that the DNS record for focal.exapmle.net and _kerebros._udp.example.net are not set anymore, so:

1 - what are they for? Kerebros I think is the part that makes the connections between linux samba and windows, right?

2 - are they local DNSs to the samba machine?

3 - can I add them back to the DNS record somehow?

Comment: TL:DR how are you setting up your SAMBA share and where. [edit] you question to include - don't add to the comment trail

Comment: what do you mean samba share? like a file server? or the path of the samba config file perhaps?

Comment: the only things i found are these, but i don't feel it's what you mean either:

\\smbdc1\netlogon

\\smbdc1\sysvol\example.net\Policies

\\smbdc1\sysvol\example.net\scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being redirected [here](https://lists.samba.org/mailman/listinfo/samba) by [Rowland](https://serverfault.com/a/1112900/987417), I was able to reach someone that found the problem instantly!

Windows11 version 22H2 is not compatible with Samba 4.15 and I'm now trying to upgrade to Samba 4.16 to fix it!

...it just happened that all the PCs I was trying to join to the domain were all fresh Win11 installs and so I never caught the discrepency (still works on older versions of windows).